# How can I use OAuth in my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, oauth

I want to use OAuth (documentation from http://fdp.frogcommunity.com/questions/view/171/introducing-oauth) in my app, any ideas/online tutorials listing how to do it using the code listed in the link above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using this

[OAuthConsumer Implementation for Objective-C](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/)

It's been working great so far